# "which" as relative determiner?

Tags: relative-clauses, determiners

Sentence 1： I was told my work was unsatisfactory, **at which point** I submitted my resignation.

Sentence 2：Sometimes you may feel too frail to cope with things, **in which case** do them as soon as it is convenient.

I am confused with "which" in the above two sentences. Does it serve relative determiner, rather than relative pronoun?
Does "which point" in the first sentence stand for "I was told my work was unsatisfactory"?Does "which case" in the second sentence stand for "sometimes you may feel too frail to cope with things"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You understand this precisely. CGEL (398-9) identifies *which*, *what*, *whichever* and *whatever* as *relative determinatives* and remarks that

> The only relative determinative found outside the fused construction is *which*. It occurs in supplementary but not integrated relatives.

The ‘fused construction’ is also known as the ‘free relative’ construction, so CGEL is speaking here of the use of *which* in *bound relative clauses*, as in your examples.

The supplementary/integrated distinction is more widely known as that between nonrestrictive and restrictive relative clauses: relative determinative *which* is not used in restrictive relatives. In Present-Day English the noun it determines (*point* and *case* in your examples) almost always refers to the entire head clause or to some implicit aspect of that clause’s content

> At the point at which I was told that my work was unsatisfactory I submitted my resignation.
>
> In a case in which you feel to frail to deal with things, do them as soon as is convenient.