# Can *which* act as a definite article meaning *the*?

Tags: grammar

I heard the sentence from a non-native:

> *He spoke in Greek, which language I could only follow with difficulty.*

Here, *which* attracts my attention! Has it been used correctly? Normally I would say *the (very) language*.

Comment: Related: [“which” as relative determiner?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/which-as-relative-determiner).

Comment: @Cardinal edited: from a non-native

Comment: The sentence makes sense and is grammatically correct, but the construction using *which* isn't commonly used these days in casual conversation.

Comment: I think it's grammatical. The relativised element here is not just "which", but the whole object NP "which language", and it's this phrase that derives its interpretation from the antecedent "Greek". I suspect your unease is caused by the fact that "which" most often occurs as an interrogative determiner as in "Which languages do you speak"? In your example, "which" is a determiner, but it's not interrogative.

Answer (score 1):

No, *which* begins a new phrase usually.  So after *which* will follow a subject/verb/etc, or those will be elided and implied.

*Which* can be a pronoun in a question, though.

> I took the book off the shelf.
>
> I took which book off the shelf (doesn't work)
>
> You took which book off the shelf? (works)
>
> Did you see the book Jason had?  No, I couldn't find which one (= I couldn't find which one Jason had).

*Whichever* works more like a determiner/article:

> I wanted to buy a car today.  The one which Jason was talking about.
>
> I wanted to buy whichever car today that Jason was talking about.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the OP's example. Wouldn't you consider "which" to be a relative determiner?

Comment: It sounds better if it was said "He spoke in Greek, which is a language I could only follow with difficulty."

Comment: I think BillJ is correct, it's just that this usage of "which" is kind of archaic these days.

Comment: Yes, but to be fair to the OP, we were considering the example he cited. Relatives with "which" as a determiner do seem quite rare. Relative determiner "which" only occurs in certain supplementary (non-defining) relatives where the relativised element (including the head noun) has a 'superordinate' NP as antecedent. And supplementary (non-defining) relatives are, I believe, the least frequent type - so maybe those factors contribute to the comparative rarity of such constructions.